# What does this warning mean for shapely python

Tags: python, geopandas

The program keep outputting:

> /Users/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas/_compat.py:106: UserWarning: The Shapely GEOS version (3.8.0-CAPI-1.13.1 ) is incompatible with the GEOS version PyGEOS was compiled with (3.9.1-CAPI-1.14.2). Conversions between both will be slow.
> warnings.warn(

when the program below is written:

```
   import numpy as np
   import pandas as pd
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   import geopandas as gpd
   from descartes import PolygonPatch
   from shapely.geometry import Point Polygon
```

I have tried to solve this researching for hours but don't know what it means and when I try to do any program related to shapely the incorrect solution is outputted.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Could you please provide a code snippet so we can get an understanding of what is going on?

Comment: This is a warning, not an error.

Comment: Do you know what this warning means?

Comment: I don't know. Check this: https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/1652

Answer (score 8):

It's a **warning**, not an **error**. This means you will not get incorrect answers. The warning has a clear message, the final sentence:

```
Conversions between both will be slow.
```

You're potentially losing some performance. That's it; you can safely ignore it.

Check an answer like this if you'd like to suppress this specific warning:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463277/how-to-disable-python-warnings

If you want to know a little more: pygeos and shapely are both Python packages wrapping a C++ library, called GEOS. GEOS is the topological suite that is used to e.g. compute intersections between polygons: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JTS_Topology_Suite#C/C++_port:_GEOS

Historically, geopandas has used shapely to represent vector geometries. However, shapely is somewhat slow; pygeos is essentially a "vectorized" re-implementation of shapely, and can be much faster. See:
https://pygeos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#relationship-to-shapely

You might be mixing shapely and pygeos vector data. E.g. geopandas would like to store geometry via pygeos, but you might be supplying it with shapely geometries. In this case, it might convert the geometry, but due to different versions of GEOS in the background, it has to do more work to go from one or the other. That's what the warning is telling you.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: Is there a package upgrade that would make the warning go away? I started getting this warning when I upgraded from geopandas 0.8.1  to 0.10.2 and I am wondering if I upgrade something else it will go away.

Comment: @M.O. -- this worked for me: `python -m pip install --upgrade shapely`